# 'Object reference not set' after changing doc type

Tags: umbraco

I made a change to a document type (renamed a property and its alias, and added another property) and now a user control that calls node.ChildrenAsTable("doctypealias") is giving 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. I've confirmed that node != null.

I'm using Umbraco 4.7.0. on a dedicated web server (full trust) running IIS7.

I've tried recycling app pool, restarting IIS, deleting umbraco.config, touching web.config, re-uploading the user control, republishing entire site. Nothing works.

To clarify, the user control gets the current node, and tries then to call ChildrenAsTable() on the current node. The current node's children are pages of the doctype that I edited.

Please help!!

Comment: Hi James, does the "Object reference not set" error occur when trying to edit the given node, or when trying to visit it on the front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried republishing the node or republishing the entire site as this can sometimes help this issue where a doctype changes but the content doesn't get republished (so there is a mismatch between the DB and the published XML file).

Comment: Yes, thanks Tim. I actually fixed this some time ago, but forgot to post. I had to simply go through each child node and manually rebuplish them one by one. Republishing entire site didn't work...